# remove R level of unlisted object

Tags: r, list, vector, levels

I have a variable named 'feedb'
Here it is when it was called :

```
> feedb
[[1]]
[1] Nocoment
319 Levels:  - --- ... Variasu barang ditambah

[[2]]
[1] Mantao
319 Levels:  - --- ... Variasu barang ditambah

[[3]]
[1] Tolong takpilkan no resi pengiriman.
319 Levels:  - --- ... Variasu barang ditambah
```

I do not know where '319 Levels : - --- ... Variasu barang ditambah' comes from. And I do unlist of that variable

```
abc<-unlist(feedb)
```

and it still has level :

```
> abc
[1] Nocoment                                Mantao                              
[3] Tolong takpilkan no resi pengiriman.
319 Levels:  - --- ... Variasu barang ditambah
```

What is this Levels? and how to remove it? I want that abc contains only the value. i tried StringAsFactor=FALSE but it cannot be used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `droplevels` to drop the unused levels or call `factor` again.  It should have happened when a `factor` column or `vector` got subsetted, but the `levels` of the original vector still remains.

```
 feedb[] <- lapply(feedb, droplevels)
```

Or

```
 feedb[] <- lapply(feedb, factor)
```

Or convert to `character`

```
 feedb[] <- lapply(feedb, as.character)
```